# Whats wrong with this header code?

Tags: php

```
$return_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: /logout?msg=You must login to view that page&c=2&path=$return_url");
```

For some reason its taking me  to `http://my.domain/login?msg=You%20must%20login%20to%20view%20that%20page&c=2`

when it should take me to

to `http://my.domain/login?msg=You%20must%20login%20to%20view%20that%20page&c=2&path=/blogs/write`

if i echo `$return_url`  it returns the right path...

So i'm not sure whats up. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the urlencode function like so:

```
header("Location: /logout?msg=".urlencode("You must login to view that page")."&c=2&path=".urlencode($return_url);
```

In addition, it seems like your logout page is also redirecting to /login.  View the sequence of requests which occur using an HTTP Proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: @Keverw Also, include the HTTP response headers you see when you hit the page that includes your php code.

Comment: Thanks! I got it... I feel stupid. logout.php went to login.php but i didn't have it carry over the path variable. My own fault. You get best answer.